# How to toggle classes on click?

Tags: javascript, class, icons, toggle

I know this is a simple question but I have been playing around with no success. 
I have the following code

```
<a id="mute"><i class="icon-volume"></i></a>
```

I want to be able to toggle the class .icon-volume to .icon-volume-off when clicking.

After anyone who can help!
Thanks

Comment: You say no success, what did you try?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use jQuery

```
$('#mute').on('click', function () {
    var el = $(this).find('i');
    if (el.hasClass('icon-volume')) {
         el.removeClass('icon-volume');
         el.addClass('icon-volume-off');
    } else {
        el.removeClass('icon-volume-off');
        el.addClass('icon-volume');
    }
});
```

Or you could just add the `icon-volume-off` class and make sure its css takes precedence over the `icon-volume` class

```
$('#mute').on('click', function () {
    var el = $(this).find('i');
    if (el.hasClass('icon-volume-off')) {
         el.removeClass('icon-volume-off');
    } else {
        el.addClass('icon-volume-off');
    }
});
```

Comment: The user is asking for Javascript, not jQuery. The Javascript tag specifically says `Unless a tag for a framework/library is also included, a pure JavaScript answer is expected.`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
    var a = document.getElementById("mute");
    a.onclick = function(e){
     var cl = a.firstChild.getAttribute('class');
     if(cl == "icon-volume"){ 
      a.firstChild.setAttribute('class','icon-volume-off');
     }else{
      a.firstChild.setAttribute('class','icon-volume');
     } 
   };
```

See demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/evvUb/)

Comment: How does this toggle the class?

Answer (score 0):

**WARNING**: This is a (relatively) new attribute. Check the [compatibility table from Mozilla's Developer Network](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element.classList#Browser_compatibility) before you proceed. If IE 9 (or below) is important to you, then this is not the answer you're looking for.

DOM elements have a property called `classList`. The 3 methods you should familiarize yourself with are `add`, `remove`, and `toggle`.

In your case:

```
var el = document.querySelector('i');
el.onclick = function () {
    el.classList.toggle('icon-volume');
    el.classList.toggle('icon-volume-off');
}
```

Pretty simple.